# use common math library in java

Tags: java, linear-regression

I am newbie to java and now I want to apply the **ordinary linear regression** to two series, say [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

I learn that there is a library called common `math`. However, the documentation is difficult to understand, is there any **example** to do simple ordinary linear regression in java?

Comment: have you checked out http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression?

Comment: Can you please explain what your expected output is?

Comment: I don't think math has regression functions. Use Apache Commons Math instead: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html

Comment: What I want to do is calculate the beta.

Comment: I used to be using Python. In Python, once I import the stat module, I can directly use the function inside the module. However, in Java, I try the same thing but it does not work.

Comment: @Dims Thanks. The problem I have is that I do not know how to implement it, do you have a simple example that I can go through?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [math3 library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) you can do the way below. Sample is based on [`SimpleRegression`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) class:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class Try_Regression {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating regression object, passing true to have intercept term
        SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression(true);

        // passing data to the model
        // model will be fitted automatically by the class 
        simpleRegression.addData(new double[][] {
                {1, 2},
                {2, 3},
                {3, 4},
                {4, 5},
                {5, 6}
        });

        // querying for model parameters
        System.out.println("slope = " + simpleRegression.getSlope());
        System.out.println("intercept = " + simpleRegression.getIntercept());

        // trying to run model for unknown data
        System.out.println("prediction for 1.5 = " + simpleRegression.predict(1.5));

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Dims,

I have two lists, i.e. xList and yList. The values are populated using a loop.
As the values are unknown to me, is there any possible way I can apply the above solution.
For example, I am trying to do like this:
 
                   ` for(int m=0; i< segmentI; i++)
                    {
                            simpleRegression.addData(new double[][]{
                                    {xList.get(m),yList.get(m)}
                            });

                    }`

Comment: You should either use another method http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html#addData(double,%20double)

i.e.  simpleRegression.addData(xList.get(m),yList.get(m))

Comment: or concatenate your list properly